# How to bind SQL Server data to SharePoint 2013 Master page using C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I have an C# solution where I already imported custom `seattle.master` page.

For that page, in top ribbon I have to dynamically bind data from SQL Server data. Whenever the user clicks on the URL on top ribbon data should be bind from SQL Server table.

Do I need to create class for the existing master template in my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could develop a custom web part to call the data from SQL Server instead of import C# Solution to your master page.

Please check this demo to create custom web part and call SQL Database:

[Calling SQL Server from SharePoint Web-Part with Impersonation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/09/15/calling-sql-server-from-sharepoint-web-part-with-impersonation/)